# Are there any good tilesets for hex-based maps that are available for free use?

Tags: tiles, assets

Does anyone know of any good tilesets for hex-based maps that are available for free use? The tiles from Battle for Wesnoth seem to be under a license that would allow others to use them in their games, but the game I'm developing is on a scale where a hex would be about equivalent to the area that a person would stand on, whereas the Wesnoth tiles are on a larger scale (for example, there are forest tiles with multiple trees on the hex). Are there any other games or other sources that have hex tile graphics available?

Answer (score 4):

[OpenGameArt.org](http://opengameart.org/) has several hex tile-sets.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the Might and Magic Online game, it uses hexagon tiles but they are transparent.

I mean the playing ground is designed differently then the places where the hexagon tiles go.

Am I making any sense?

url for the game [Might & Magic Online](http://homm.91.com/index/)

Comment: The Might and Magic graphics are under copyright, and wouldn't be usable in other games.

Comment: Who said anything about USING these textures? The idea was to that the author of the post would make his/her own textures for the game instead of using/copying them from another game.

Comment: The question is "Does anyone know of any good tile sets for hex-based maps that are available for use?"  Implying that the author planned on using the tiles for their game.  If the question was simply "what games use hex tiles", then there's plenty of possible answers.

Comment: "available for use" doesn't necessitate that they're royalty free. Placeholder graphics are almost always used in a prerelease version of a game, so it's not unreasonable to assume that's what the OP meant.

...of course it would also help if there was somewhere you could actually download the images xD